# JSON circular reference in asp mvc 5

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting an a Circular Reference Serialization Error and failed to load result...status of 500.

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown list with the options from the database, appending options with js.

those are my class:

```
public class IdentificacionViewModel
{ public virtual Causas Causas { get; set; }
  public virtual Identificacion Idententificacion { get; set; }
} 


public partial class Causas
{ 


    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Causa { get; set; }
    public string Agente { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id_Subproceso { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id_identificacion { get; set; }

    public virtual Identificacion Identificacion { get; set; }
    public virtual Subprocesos Subprocesos { get; set; }
}

public Identificacion()
    {
        this.Causas = new HashSet<Causas>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Id_Servicio { get; set; }
    public string Etapa { get; set; }
    public string Riesgo { get; set; }
    public string EfectoProb { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Causas> Causas { get; set; }
    public virtual Servicios Servicios { get; set; }
    public virtual Impacto Impacto { get; set; }
}
```

my controller is:

```
public ActionResult GetA()
    {
        var category = db.Causas.ToList();
         return Json(category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

i don't know what could be the problem and thanks for the help.

Comment: You should create a ViewModel to return just the data you need.  Don't try and return the data model, because you'll run into all sorts of problems, not to mention a lot of data going over the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lazy Loading of the Causas collection can be turned off by making the Causas property non-virtual

```
public ICollection<Causas> Causas { get; set; }
```

Loading of the Causas collection can still be achieved using eager loading

```
 var Identification = context.Identificacion
                   .Include(b => b.Causas) 
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank for your help, it was so simple but i was losing my head for that.